# file_get_contents() returns garbled data

Tags: php, stackexchange-api

I am trying to use the SO API (eg: http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/users/3) to get some data:

```
<?php

$data = file_get_contents('http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/users/3');
echo $data;

?>
```

But the returned contents are garbled. I tested it on a couple different servers, including http://codepad.viper-7.com/9GFvsM. Is it my code or the API?

Comment: Hmmm... Maybe this is gzipped?

Comment: (0) belongs on meta, or even stackapps.com (1) how are they garbled?

Comment: (0) Not really if it's a programming problem (it is) (1) There is a link on my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response is gzipped.  I recommend you use [curl](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) and set `CURLOPT_ENCODING` to gzip.

Comment: It shouldn't be gzipped if the client didn't request it as such, should it?

Comment: @Pekka See http://stackapps.com/questions/729/server-has-stopped-obeying-accept-encoding-header

Comment: @Artefacto cheers. I agree with `Then the server should send a 406 response`.